# How to keep showing pagination bar in DataTables if there are no records/total # of records are being shown?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatables

I am using `DataTables` and I need to show the pagination bar all the times if there are no records or if total number of records are being displayed. Currently the pagination bar hides if there are no records and if total number of records are being shown. There is no need to paginate in both cases but is there a property to have the pagination bar in place in both cases. My JQuery looks like the following

JQuery

```
var table = $('#esignTable').DataTable({"sDom": '<"top"flp>rt<"bottom"i><"clear">',
      pagingType: 'input',
      pageLength: 12,
      language: {
        "sEmptyTable": " ",
        oPaginate: {
            sNext: '<i class="fa fa-forward"></i>',
            sPrevious: '<i class="fa fa-backward"></i>',
            sFirst: '<i class="fa fa-step-backward"></i>',
            sLast: '<i class="fa fa-step-forward"></i>'
        }
      }   
    });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can retrieve number of pages and show hidden pagination control if there is only one page.

```js
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
   pagingType: 'input',
   drawCallback: function(){
       var api = this.api();
       var container = api.table().container();

       var info = api.page.info();
       if(info.pages === 1){
           $('.dataTables_paginate', container).show();
           $('.paginate_input, .paginate_page', container).hide();
       } else {           
           $('.paginate_input, .paginate_page', container).show();          
       }
   }
});
```

See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/7bxwhvzv/1/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: it is doing the trick but why it is removing the input field?

Comment: @David, I don't see the sense in showing pagination for 1 page or empty input field. You can adjust the code by not hiding input field, if needed.

Comment: You are right, but this is the requirement. Anyways, thank you for helping me out.